# VS2019 - VSTS - .NET Core 3.1 : %LAUNCHER_PATH% gets replaced

Tags: visual-studio, web-config

I need to deploy a **.NET Core API** on a remote **IIS server** with **VSTS**

But Visual Studio changes **web.config**, modifying the variable **processPath** to my local IIS config, every time I run the app locally, **even if I change it**

```
<aspNetCore processPath="some_local_path_not_existing_on_remote_server\myapi.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess">
```

so **when I deploy** the app, the **path does not match the remote server** paths

I tried using **%LAUNCHER_PATH%** in web.config, **it gets replaced too**

I could use VSTS to replace the values in web.config, but %LANCHER_PATH% is more portable

why is it getting replaced when I run the app localy ? how to avoid this ?

regards

Comment: Did you get a solution for the issues?

Comment: no, nobody else seems to have the problem

Comment: The only thing which seemed to solve it for me was to installing the the hosting bundle and it added some values to the path which allow it to resolve correctly. But expecting it to resurface at some point